# Cлова, удовлетворяющие регулярному выражению

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Всем привет!

Простая задача, но никак не могу сообразить.

`Построить  регулярные  выражения,  задающих  множество 
всех таких слов над словарем  E = {a, b, c}, в которых за символом b:
1)  обязательно следует символ c;
2)  не может находиться символ c.`

Первую сделал: `(a|c|bc)+`

Для второй: `(?(?<=b)(a|b)|.)+`

Но задача осложняется тем, что нельзя использовать просмотр назад/вперед и поиск по условию, т. е. второе задание выполнено неверно.

Заранее большое спасибо!

ps. Протестировать можно на:

```
abc
acb

bac
bca

cab
cba

cabcabcbacbcaaaccbbaaccacbac
```

---

Ответ: `c*(cc|ac*|b|a)*[ab]*`

Не уверен, что оптимальный и абсолютно правильный, но тестовые примеры прошел.

Comment: А вы уверены, что первое задание у вас выполнено правильно? Если да, то по аналогии 2-е: http://regex101.com/r/bT0lO8

Comment: @MDJHD, первое верно. В Вашем варианте ошибка в том, что просто `b` тоже допустимый вариант. Как и `ab`.

Нужно как-то впихнуть отдельно `b`, но так, чтобы `bc` было недопустимо..

Comment: А препод ваш сказал вам, что первое у вас правильно? Просто я вижу ответ на первое задание таким http://regex101.com/r/qQ2fZ6 , а вы у себя match'ите просто символы, а в задании указано "слова"

Comment: Но я не отрицаю, что не правильно понимаю само определение задачи

Comment: @MDJHD, отдельные символы - это тоже слова, но если встречается символ `b`, то за ним не должно быть `c`. 

То есть, например, в `abc` должно найтись `ab` и отдельно `c`

Comment: @MDJHD, сделайте что-нибудь ответом, чтобы я мог принять вопрос :)

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Veikedo, сделал :) Но так и не понял, решили вы задание или нет. Если да, то разместите, если не сложно, правильный ответ. Сам просто недавно начал более глубоко изучать регулярки.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

И тогда второе как-то так: http://regex101.com/r/iJ3eP9

Comment: Контрпример bbc